# Change wordpress post category colors

Tags: php, wordpress, function, colors, wordpress-theming

I have a navigation bar on my wordpress blog which displays post categories. I would like each category to have a different background color on the nav bar and when displayed on other pages. I found the following php code for the functions.php file, and it works to add a selection box for colors in the post categories admin page. The color selection box works, however this code does not change colors on the site on its own. I'm new to wordpress and need to know what other files need to be edited and in what way to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
add_action('edit_category_form', 'add_extra_fields');
add_action('edited_category', 'save_extra_fields');
function add_extra_fields($tag)
{
    $colors = array('Black' => '000', 'White' => 'FFF');
    $selected = get_option('category_'.$tag->term_id.'_color');
    echo '<select name="cat_color">';
    foreach($colors as $name => $hex)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$hex.'"'.($hex == $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
function save_extra_fields($term_id)
{
    if($_POST['cat_color'])
    {
        update_option('category_'.$term_id.'_color', $_POST['cat_color']);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to, you need to modify your navigation bar code to use the new meta data from your form.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm new to wordpress. Do I need to add a 'container' to the nav array with $term_id ?